# How do I get multiple add hoc builds under one provisioning profile?

Tags: iphone, ios

I want two ad-hoc builds of my app to be be able to be installed at the same time on one device.

I do not want to make an additional ad-hoc provisioning profile. (which is how I have done it in the past).

The **bundle identifier** can not be changed since doing so will require a new provisioning profile.

If there is an answer it will have something to do with changing a particular name.  Can someone explain what each of these names mean and tell me if changing them will help me get two builds?

- **product name**
- **bundle display name**
- **bundle name**
- **executable file**

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make a wildcard provisioning profile.  Set up a new appID in the provisioning portal. You simply make somthing like: com.myCompany.*.  Then use that identifier in a new ad-hoc profile.  Then any app that has an identifier that starts with com.myCompany can work with that profile.  This has to be done in the iOS provisioning portal though.

Comment: You cant do this for ad hoc builds.

Comment: Yes you can.  We do all of our Ad-Hoc distributions like this.  I just set one up now to verify it works.

Comment: Oh ok then, I thought I tried this a while ago with no success. Ill give it another go, Thanks.